# Surpress all Core Data console output

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

Is there a way to hide all output relating to both `CoreData` and `CoreData: CloudKit` from showing in my console? I'm working on another area of my app but don't want to have to manually disable all of this code and instead would like if I could just hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get rid of the majority by adding these arguments

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 0
-com.apple.CoreData.CloudKitDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 0
```

To `Scheme>Edit Scheme>Run>Arguments>Arguments Passed At Launch`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I had some of those already but the key was the first two for `CloudKit` and `stderr`

Comment: Where can we find these? How do folks figure them out?

Comment: @BeauNouvelle I got these from searching around online but it is a standard [logger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code) pattern you could fish around for the log files that are created and see the domain there.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you. Will take a look. At least I have a place to start looking now.